# Eclipse, copy java class ( or move ) and all referenced and used classes

Tags: eclipse

The reason is that I have tons of other classes and packages and want a clean copy of one class and all classes and packages that it uses, so that I will have a copy in another directory or project that is "clean" and working.

Thanks!

Comment: Eclipse, copy java class ( or move ) and all referenced and used classes in that class.

Comment: Sounds like a job for version control system, no?

Answer (score -1):

Move the class with update references checked (the default) and then copy it back to the original location?

Comment: Well, not really. I want a clean copy, meaning that I dont point to old classes. I just want to extract this one class and all its related classes. I dont think this is possible in eclipse however. I would have to do this manually.

Comment: Yes, I think you are right, copy everything and chop out all of the stuff you don't need by hand.